# Any drawbacks in partitioning 2 SSDs running in RAID0?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I bought a laptop that comes with 2x256GB SSD drives pre-configured in RAID0.
It has one volume of 512gb.
I want to split it in 2 volumes to have my windows separated from my personal files.

Are there any drawbacks in performance if I do this or anything I should be aware of when partitioning?

Comment: Raid 0 has no redundancy. Perhaps you meant to say RAID1?

Comment: @EricF: RAID 0 looks better from a marketing perspective.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Are you joking or serious?

Comment: @EricF: I'm being only a *little* facetious.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Never can tell on here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are perfectly fine to *partition* the RAID-0 volume.  There will be no performance loss either.

Just be aware that in a RAID-0 configuration, if one drive were to die, you would lose the entire volume and all the partitions.  As always, make backups.

If you *split the RAID* volume and have two individual drives, you will lose performance, as RAID-0 (AKA striping) splits reading and writing evenly amongst the drives for increased speed.  This is assuming your disk controller was fast enough to benefit from the increased read/write speed of the RAID-0 volume.

Comment: In laptop hardware it is highly doubtful there is any benefit of a RAID0 of SSD's. Even desktop systems don't gain any meaningful performance benefit. It is only in some high-end workstations (that actually use server chipsets) and servers that such a thing makes sense and even then only if you have a workload that can make use of it. But it really does look good in the marketing material.

Comment: Except that RAID0 gives you the illusion of 1 big drive so you don't need to worry about balancing your data. I'm not sure it provides any benefits over JBOD in a laptop though, and an abstraction layer like lvm under Linux is better again.